# FusionPBX and Freeswitch

Tags: xml, freeswitch, fusionpbx

I have a question, which seems strange !
I know that `Freeswitch` is a SIP Server that acts as a SIP Registrar via `Sofia` module and `XML` base `Dialplan`.
In `Freeswitch` we can create extensions via `XML` handly. 
In other side we have a good solution for managing and administrating Freeswitch called `FusionPBX`, It read and write data such as extensions and other configures and conference data in `Postgres` or `Mysql` database.
And when you create an extension via FusionPBX and in `GUI` interface, it creates a field in database, and no `XML` is created,right? 
After creating extension in `FusionPBX` and then we go to the `Freeswitch cli` and enter `user_exist` command, it display the user does not exists.
My question is that how `FusionPBX` contacts with `Freeswitch`? How it registers extensions in `FS`? How can it start, stop `Freeswitch` services?
And how it access `Freeswitch` services and other functionality?
Via `WebService`? Direct access? If direct access how can it be possible? which way?

Answer (score 0):

FreeSWITCH has an embedded language called Lua. Lua is configured to serve XML from information in the database and then cache it. This approach has many advantages over XML sitting inside FreeSWITCH's configuration directory. In order for Lua to build the XML it has to be able to connect to FusionPBX's database which is easy if FusionPBX data is in SQLite because its a native language for FreeSWITCH. If using PostgreSQL it requires a PostgreSQL driver which is installed by default with an official FusionPBX install script. If using MySQL you have to setup ODBC and tell FusionPBX's Lua scripts how to use that ODBC connection. For a scalable system the easiest approach is to use PostgreSQL and an official install script from https://github.com/fusionpbx/fusionpbx-install.sh.

Answer (score -1):

the issue is no XML created , /var/www/fusionpbx/app/    this directoy has many php files, they can create XML files

and you can  enter  cmd : service freeswitch stop/start

Comment: hi, did the issue has fixed ?     May I  disscuss with you about the issue ?   my e-mail  is  zwf@synway.cn   thank you

Comment: I will mail you
Thanks sir